# ¿Cómo bloquear el botón submit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Cómo podría bloquear el botón `submit` en `html` para evitar el doble envío de un formulario?

Tengo este código pero no funciona:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {

document.forms['form'].addEventListener('submit', avisarUsuario);

}



function avisarUsuario(evObject) {

evObject.preventDefault();

var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.btn btn-success');

for (var i=0; i<botones.length; i++) {botones[i].disabled = true; }

var nuevoNodo = document.createElement('h2');

nuevoNodo.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color:orange;">Enviando... espere por favor</h2>';

document.body.appendChild(nuevoNodo);

var retrasar = setTimeout(procesaDentroDe2Segundos, 1000);

}



function procesaDentroDe2Segundos() {document.forms['form'].submit();}

</script>
```

Comment: puedes mostrar también donde llamas a las funciones? (codigo HTML)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar lo siguiente, agrega primero la referencia de `jquery`:

Ejemplo:

```
html:
<html>
  <header> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</header>
    <form id="miforma" action="">
    <p><input type="submit" value="enviar" /></p>
    </form>
</html>
```

Declaras la siguiente función:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').find('input[type=submit]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado al final con esto: <input class="button primary" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Enviando.. .';this.form.submit();" name="commit" value="Enviar" type="submit">

Answer (score 2):

Añade un **script** en la pagina y añade esto:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
```

Donde pone "myBtn" lo cambias por el ID del submit.

Espero que te sirva